# Linux disk partitioning: no /boot?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, debian, devuan

Installing Linux, I see no option to create a /boot partition. 
Is it still needed?

Should I create a "Reserved BIOS boot area"?

In the default partitioning scheme, none of these are present.

Note: I am installing Linux without Systemd.

---

Devuan 2/Debian 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a separate `/boot` partition is needed **if the bootloader would otherwise be unable to access your kernel file** (and/or the bootloader's own additional files). For example:

- When the rootfs uses a filesystem type not understood by the bootloader (such as ZFS, XFS, multi-device btrfs…) or just not supported reliably enough.
- When the rootfs is encrypted using a method not understood by the bootloader. (E.g. GRUB can unlock LUKS volumes, but syslinux cannot.)

If your distribution's installer does not offer /boot by default, then it has chosen a combination that already works without it.

Your init system is not relevant as it only starts much later in the boot process.

---

Additionally, some firmware types require a *firmware* boot partition (e.g. UEFI needs an "EFI system partition") in which the bootloader resides. If your firmware requires one, then a well-written OS installer will always create it.

Logically this partition is separate from Linux `/boot`, but it's fine to use the same partition for both jobs (may even make things easier). Otherwise, `/efi` or `/boot/efi` are also common mount locations.

---

Finally, the "Reserved BIOS boot area" partition is needed for just **one** specific case: using the GRUB 2 bootloader on a BIOS system, but on a GPT-partitioned disk.

It is generally not needed for any other combination, and *never* needed on UEFI (as the EFI System Partition already performs the same task).

This partition is completely separate from `/boot` and does not contain anything mountable.

Answer (score 3):

Separate `/boot` partition isn't mandatory, `/boot` can be stored on root partition just as well. If you're not going to use full disk encryption, then you probably don't need separate `/boot`.

Comment: I would encrypt /home only.

Comment: Then you probably don't need `/boot` partition. Go ahead and install without it. If you ever need it, it's quite simple to create it: create an ext4 partition, move everything from `/boot` to that partition, add it to `/etc/fstab` to mount at `/boot`, done.

Comment: What about the "Reserved BIOS boot area"? Can I ignore it?

Comment: See [this question on related site](https://askubuntu.com/a/929051/129094).

Comment: @kostix That's completely opposite to what the link I've posted says. Can you provide any sources to back your statements?

Comment: Yes, you're correct and I am not. Will delete my silly comment.